# Cannot access 'split': it is private in file

Tags: android, string, kotlin, split

I develop an app with `Kotlin` and got this weird error today in *Android Studio*, so I tried the same code  in *InteliJ Idea* as well, where I get the same behaviour. I've used the `split` method so far in my Android project and it worked always like a charm.

This is the code where this behaviour appears:

```
        val rawString = "OK;ABC;34"       
        val delimited = rawString.split(";",true,0).last()
```

So today, the compiler says that the `split` method cannot be reached, because it is private in file. Go figure!

In the code above, I'm trying to get the `String` "34" into my `delimited` variable. Are there any restrictions that I'm missing or are there any changes made on this method?

[image: error with split method]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the import say on top of your file for the function "split" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use like the below, split that you have used is a private function in `Strings.kt` class

```
 val rawString = "OK;ABC;34"
 val delimited = rawString.split(";", ignoreCase = true, limit = 0).last()
```